# LINQ selection and sorting with different relations

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a `DBSet<User>` of users. Each User has a `DBSet<Activity>`of activities. Each activity itself has one or no Category with a name.

```
public class User
{
    [...]
    DBSet<Activity> activity {get;set;}
}

public class Activity
{
    [...]
    Category category{get;set;}
}

public class Category
{
    [...]
    string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Now i want to have a List of all users sorted by the number of occurrences of a given category name in activites. In other words: I want a list of users ordered by the number of his activities in a category.  How can i do that with LINQ (lambda expressions)?

```
DBSet<User> users;
string cat="myCategory";
var usersByCategoryActivity = users.OrderByDescending(???);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
string cat="myCategory";
DBSet<User> users;
    var usersByCategory = users
             .OrderBy(e=> e.activity.Count(a => a.Categories.Name.Contains(cat)));
```

Comment: thanks. I had also to add a `where(a=>a.Category!=null)`before `Count` because categories can also be null. But this is the solution

Comment: @zoidbergi  Just add that Where predicate to the Count which already takes a predicate like so.  .OrderBy(e=> e.activity.Count(a =>  a.Category != null && a.Categories.Name.Contains(cat)));

Comment: is this faster than the nested .Where?

Comment: @zoidbergi You would have to profile SQL to know for certain, but I would imagine it is simpler for EF to generate a more optimized query for a single predicate than an aggregate predicate built off another predicate.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
DBSet<User> users;
string cat = "myCategory";
var usersByCategoryActivity = users
             .OrderByDescending(u => u.Activities
                            .Where(a => a.Categories.Select(c => c.Name)
                                                    .Contains(cat)
                            .Count()
                     );
```

If you look inside the query first, it retrieves all the activities which contains the given category. It count it all for a user, and order by that.
I'm not sure this is what you need, but your description is not precise, and there is not a samples of data. So it maybe be good enough. Maybe not.

Comment: Count has an overload that takes a predicate.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
var usersByCategory = users.ToList().OrderBy(e=>e.activity.Count());
```

Comment: this does not include the category name

Comment: Didnt see that part of question. I think Scorpi0 has your answer.